# How do I change the style(color) of tabs in action bar v7 of android ?

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I'm trying this to change the color and style of tabs in action bar using the v7 support library. But only the color of action bar is changed not the tabs. Please tell me what I'm doing wrong.

```
<!-- the theme applied to the application or activity -->
<style name="CustomActionBarTheme"
       parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">


    <!-- Support library compatibility -->
    <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
    <item name="actionBarTabStyle">@style/TabStyle</item>
</style>

<!-- ActionBar styles -->
<style name="MyActionBar"
       parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionBar.Solid.Inverse">


    <!-- Support library compatibility -->
    <item name="background">@color/action_bar</item>
</style>

<style name="TabStyle"
    parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ActionBar.TabView">

    <item name="background">@drawable/tab_bar_background</item>
</style>
```

Comment: Hi theanilpaudel, have you solved the problem? if so please tell the correct solution, then other persons who have same problem will know what's correct solution, thanks!

Comment: Not exactly, I'm still trying this and will post it here if I found the solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this (if you use actionbar tabs):

```
<style name="ActionBarTabs" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionBar.TabView.Inverse">
    <item name="titleTextStyle">@style/ActionBarTitle</item>
    <item name="android:titleTextStyle">@style/ActionBarTitle</item>
    <item name="background">@drawable/tab_bar_background</item>
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/tab_bar_background</item>
</style>

<style name="ActionBarTabBar" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionBar.TabBar.Inverse">
    <item name="android:showDividers">middle</item>
    <item name="android:divider">@drawable/list_divider_holo_light</item>
    <item name="android:dividerPadding">8dp</item>
    <item name="android:background">@color/actionbar_background</item>
</style>

<style name="TabTextStyle" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ActionBar.TabText">
    <item name="android:textColor">@android:color/black</item>
</style>
```

and in your theme:

```
 <style name="AppTheme" parent="@style/AppBaseTheme">
    ...
    <item name="android:actionBarTabStyle">@style/ActionBarTabs</item>
    <item name="actionBarTabStyle">@style/ActionBarTabs</item>
    <item name="android:actionBarTabTextStyle">@style/TabTextStyle</item>
    <item name="actionBarTabTextStyle">@style/TabTextStyle</item>
    <item name="android:actionBarTabBarStyle">@style/ActionBarTabBar</item>
    <item name="actionBarTabBarStyle">@style/ActionBarTabBar</item>
    ...
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change the color of the menu items in the action bar you have to set the actionMenuTextColor in your theme style.

```
<style name="PortfolioTheme" parent="android:style/Theme.Holo.Light">
   <item name="android:actionMenuTextColor">#24598a</item>
   <item name="actionMenuTextColor">#24598a</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

To customise tabs color, I suppose you should change your TabStyle item to be :

```
<item name="android:actionBarTabBarStyle">@style/TabStyle</item>
```

override "android:actionBarTabBarStyle" rather than "android:actionBarTabStyle"